# Meaning of !! and how to use it

Tags: javascript, if-statement, webstorm

I am writing a code using WebStorm IDE, and I wrote an

> if statement

in a method like this:

```
createEvent():boolean {
  return this.http.post('/event', { params: {name , location} }).map(res => res.json()).map(res => {

    if(event && event.success){
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
}
```

Then the IDE suggest I rewrite (simplify) the if statement this way:

```
createEvent():boolean {
  return this.http.post('/event', { params: {name , location} }).map(res => res.json()).map(res => {
    return !!(event && event.success);
  });
}
```

**I find it confusing while the system uses a double NOT sign.**

*Please I need some explanation.*

Comment: In normal JS, this is probably used for type conversion or for making the code smaller.

Comment: Really you should just do `return event && event.success`. That already produces a *truthy* or *falsey* value. There's virtually never any place to use `if ... return true else return false`.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript